# Computer guessing a user-selected number within a defined range

Tags: python, list, indexing

This is my code for a game in which the computer must guess a user defined number within a given range. This is a challenge from a beginners course/ book.

I'd like to draw your attention to the 'computerGuess()' function. I think there must be a more eloquent way to achieve the same result? What I have looks to me like a botch job!

The purpose of the function is to return the middle item in the list (hence middle number in the range of numbers which the computer chooses from). The 0.5 in the 'index' variable equation I added because otherwise the conversion from float-int occurs, the number would round down.

Thanks.

Code:

```
# Computer Number Guesser
# By Dave
# The user must pick a number (1-100) and the computer attempts to guess
# it in as few attempts as possible


print("Welcome to the guessing game, where I, the computer, must guess your\
 number!\n")
print("You must select a number between 1 and 100.")

number = 0
while number not in range(1, 101):
    number = int(input("\nChoose your number: "))

computerNumber = 0
computerGuesses = 0
higherOrLower = ""
lowerNumber = 1
higherNumber = 101

def computerGuess(lowerNumber, higherNumber):
    numberList = []
    for i in range(lowerNumber, higherNumber):
        numberList.append(i)
    index = int((len(numberList)/2 + 0.5) -1)
    middleValue = numberList[index]
    return middleValue


while higherOrLower != "c":
    if computerGuesses == 0:
        computerNumber = computerGuess(lowerNumber, higherNumber)
    elif higherOrLower == "l":
        higherNumber = computerNumber
        computerNumber = computerGuess(lowerNumber, higherNumber)
    elif higherOrLower == "h":
        lowerNumber = computerNumber + 1
        computerNumber = computerGuess(lowerNumber, higherNumber)


    print("\nThankyou. My guess is {}.".format(computerNumber))
    computerGuesses += 1
    higherOrLower = input("\nHow did I do? If this is correct, enter\
 'c'. If your number is higher, enter 'h'. If it is lower, enter 'l': ")

print("\nHaha! I got it in {} attempt(s)! How great am I?".format\
      (computerGuesses))

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Since you are asking for a more elegant way to accomplish your goal, this question would be more appropriate for the code review site, not this one.

Comment: This probably belongs on the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review Stack Exchange, assuming **A)** the code works **and B)** it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Comment: Apologies. I'll take it to the code review site.

Comment: Apologies, I'll take it to the review site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
import math

def computerGuess(lowerNumber, higherNumber):
    return int((lowerNumber+higherNumber)/2)
```

Comment: What is the point of creating a full list of numbers? The median can be calculated from just the minimum and maximum of the range.

Comment: right :) my mistake :) I was just minimizing his code, without looking for purpose of the function :)